# Make a Footer Stick to the Bottom of the Page and have a fixed Navigation at the Top

Tags: css, header, footer, fixed

as you can tell by the title I want to have a footer stick to the bottom. I know that there are a lot of topics on that. I already read through them. But I can not get it to work, because of my navigation, which is fixed to the top.

The layout looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed">
</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfooter"></div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 40px; /* height of the navbar */
}

.navbar-fixed {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.clearfooter {
  clear: both;
  height: 30px;
}

#footer {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

I tried this [tutorial](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/). But the footer is not pinned to the bottom of the window it is further down (not in the viewport anymore). I already tried to fix it with additional padding/margin but nothing worked :(

Comment: why your #footer is position: relative; not position: fixed; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding padding to the body to push your page just create a `push` div to add some space between your fixed header and your content, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="push">&nbsp;</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.push { height:40px; }

.push:before, .push:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  zoom: 1;
}

.push:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fVpp2/1/show/

Edit here http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fVpp2/1/

Note: Added a bunch of break lines to illustrate the positioning of the footer.

(edit: jsfiddle cut my CSS, added it back.)

Answer (score 0):

I did an experiment and it worked, here is the html:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="contain">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
.header {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .contain {
        height:1500px;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 960px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .footer {
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

it has both header and footer fixed, I hope you get the clue out of it.

Comment: Sorry I might have not explained it correctly. The header should be fixed, but the footer not. The footer should always be at the bottom of the viewport. But if the viewport is too small it should show after the content.